How do I pull numbers after specific letter from varying strings within cell range and sum them?
Trying to pull numbers that follow after a specific letter and sum them. How do I do that ?
For instance, all that come after C (=200+15)

Using LEN, SEARCH as per below gives VALUE error
=SUM(MID(AS16,SEARCH("C:",AS16)+2,LEN(AS16)-SEARCH("C",AS16)))


If you have office365 you can use REGEXEXTRACT.
Like below. Formula in columnE is =REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4,"C:[0-9]+",1,0)

Then to sum the number after C:, you can use =SUM(IFERROR(TEXTAFTER(E1#,":"),0)+0)


If you have 365 but don't yet have the REGEX functions you can use:
=LET(
    d, $B$2:$B$5,
    key, $D$1,
    a, TEXTJOIN("
", TRUE, d),
    b, TEXTSPLIT(a, ":", "
", TRUE, , 0),
    f, FILTER(TAKE(b, , -1), TAKE(b, , 1) = key),
    SUM(--f)
)

Note that the argument (for delimiter or row_delimiter in the TEXTJOIN and TEXTSPLIT functions that looks like:
       "
",

is the linefeed character (CHAR(10)) which, if you enter it manually would be entered by typing ",alt-return,",,

Also please note that the total string lengths cannot exceed 32,767 characters.

Here are two alternative workarounds, if one don't have access to REGEX yet in MS365


• Formula used in cell B2
=SUM(--IFNA(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A4,"C:")&CHAR(10),CHAR(10)),0))


• Or, using TEXTJOIN() to combine all the data into one and split using TEXTSPLIT() which I have already commented in the Staging Ground comments thread:


=LET(
     a, IFNA(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,A1:A4),":",CHAR(10)),0), 
     SUM((TAKE(a,,1)="C")*DROP(a,,1)))



Do not have Regex functions unfortunately. Something to look into getting going forward that's for sure!
=SUM(--IFNA(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A4,"C:")&CHAR(10),CHAR(10)),0))
AND
=LET(
a, IFNA(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,A1:A4),":",CHAR(10)),0),
SUM((TAKE(a,,1)="C")*DROP(a,,1)))
worked perfectly!

@Adrian if that worked correctly, then please ensure to read here Thanks for sharing the feedback. glad to know it worked!

Got a new challenge. Sum all based on dates. Essentially between two dates. Have dates in column A and the same variables as before in column C. Can sum with one condition but using AND gives blank. This works =SUM(IF(A3:A8>=C1,(--IFNA(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(C3:C8,"C:")&CHAR(10),CHAR(10)),0)),""))    however this with AND gives blank:    =SUM(IF(AND(A3:A8>=A1,A3:A8<B1),(--IFNA(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(C3:C8,"C:")&CHAR(10),CHAR(10)),0)),"")) cannot figure why /what i'm missing

@Adrian do you have a screenshot please

here's the screenshot.
https://i.sstatic.net/H3QiI3xO.jpg
